# Parallel jenkins job, reads multiple files and errors

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I wrote a pipeline that runs in parallel 24 stages, and will be more in the future, part of this pipeline looks like this

```sh
    allApps = [a,b,c,d]
    parallel(prepareBuildStages(allApps))
```

and part of the method like so

```sh
  sh "helm3 secrets dec ${varsPath}/secrets.yaml"
  def secretsFile = readYaml file: "${varsPath}/secrets.yaml.dec"
//  sleep(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1)
  sh "helm3 secrets clean ."
  def varsFile = readYaml file: "${varsPath}/values.yaml"
//  sleep(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1)
  def databases = varsFile.migration
```

the problem is that when this method is called 24x at the same time it errors in lines where the sleep call is. (I assume from too many files opened and being written to at the same time) After adding sleep it started to work basically 100% of the time in 70x i ran that pipeline. But I know that's not the solution, when we'll have 100 or 200 stages the problem will most likely return. So here's my question does anyone have any idea how/what to improve ?

I'm reading right now and testing the `File Descriptor`, but I'm not sure if that's the right path.

PS: Later in pipeline I ran `gradle update`, I thought there would be an issue with it, but it seems like the gradle daemon dealt with that issue on its own

Comment: Maybe you should try to read the file before hand and simply pass the YAML (basically a map in groovy) into the function then you wouldn't have to read it 24 times

Comment: but these are 24 different files x2 because values and secrets, not just 1 file read 24 times

Comment: Parallelization is always an expensive thing. If your agent can't handle the 48 files maybe you should give it more power. There is also the possibility to execute it in batches, let's say limited to 10 each

Comment: cpu/ram usage is within limits of the agent (around 4cores/3gb ram used out of 8/8 limits), and the batches/sleeping is the thing I wanted to avoid, and run them all at the same time

Comment: you can try locks from this plugins to limit the number of files open at a time https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/
or use semaphores https://plugins.jenkins.io/concurrent-step/